# Why don't block elements expand to their children's explicit width, when there's a horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

When I shrink my (Chrome/Safari) browser window horizontally, such that the window width is less than the width of an element, a scrollbar appears. After scrolling to the right, my content's width is equal to the viewport width, but only if it doesn't have an explicit width. This results in some content being cut off.

**Simple example:**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.two {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Hello World</div>
<div class="two">Hello World</div>
```

([*codepen*](https://codepen.io/ackmanx/pen/pGLObd))

If `.one` element is block, and the width defaults to the width of its parent, why doesn't it end up being the same width as the larger `.two` element?

Is it because the width of `html` is the width of the viewport and not the document?

Comment: Example CodePen: https://codepen.io/ackmanx/pen/pGLObd

Comment: What's the behaviour you are expecting? I think you are mixing the clientWidth (the width of the element) of the body with the scrollWidth (the width of it's content) The scroll appears when the scrollWidth if greater than the clientWidth. `.one`'s width is the parent's clientWidth

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth

Comment: Because you set `.two` to 1000px?

Comment: @arieljuod I was expecting both divs to be the same width. Because I gave `.two` a width, and its parents did not have an explicit width, I thought that they would grow to match. Because `.one` does not set a width, I thought it would also expand. But in fact, `body` is the width of the visible portion of the page, and `.two` is always 1000px. My false assumption is that a child element with an explicit width should not be larger than its parent's width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing element in your analysis is the overflow part. What you said is correct because `one` will have the width of its parent but `two` will not expand the width of its parent, it will overflow it.

If you add border to the `body` and `html` element you can clearly notice this.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.two {
  width: 1000px;
}

body {
  border:2px solid;
}
html {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Hello World</div>
<div class="two">Hello World</div>
```

Starting from the viewport all the element are block level element and will have `width:100%` (`html` then `body` then `one`) BUT you made the width of `two` to be bigger which will create an overflow and won't change the width of any ancestor element.

You probably need to understand how overflow is working and how the scrollbar is added:

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the 'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport, if the value on the root element is 'visible'. The 'visible' value when used for **the viewport must be interpreted as 'auto'**. The element from which the value is propagated must have a **used value for 'overflow' of 'visible'**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow)</sup>

So basically we didn't set an overflow value so by default it's `visible` thus the viewport will have a value of `auto`. So your having scrollbar on the viewport and not the `html` or the `body`.

> auto
>
> The behavior of the 'auto' value is user agent-dependent, but should cause a scrolling mechanism to be provided for overflowing boxes.

If you disable the overflow within the `html` or the `body` you will have no scroll:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.two {
  width: 1000px;
}

body {
  border:2px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
}
html {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Hello World</div>
<div class="two">Hello World</div>
```

and the `html`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.two {
  width: 1000px;
}

body {
  border:2px solid;
}
html {
  border:2px solid green;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Hello World</div>
<div class="two">Hello World</div>
```

And if you change your `body` to `inline-block` you will notice that the width will increase depending on the content (it's no more `width:100%`):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.two {
  width: 1000px;
}

body {
  border:2px solid;
  display:inline-block;
}
html {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Hello World</div>
<div class="two">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Your very thorough answer with examples made it clear what is going on

Answer (score 1):

The width of a block-level element is, by default, that of its parent.
The width of an inline element is the width if its contents.
(`<body>` is block-level)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        .two {
            width: 1000px;
        }
        .block {
            border: 2px dotted orange;
        }
        .inline {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 2px dotted blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='block'>
    <div class='one'>Hello World</div>
    <div class='two'>Hello World</div>
  </div>
  <div class='inline'>
    <div class='one'>Hello World</div>
    <div class='two'>Hello World</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the practice, all block elements take the with of its parent, so in your example `div.one` is taking the with of the `body`, and as the body have not a specific width, then it takes the width of the `viewport` (not the `html` element).

The `div.two` elements is taking the specific with, without affecting its parent with (`body`).

Review this links:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth